# Sum cells when week num of cell from range equals something

Tags: excel, ms-office, sumifs

How to sum cells from a range when cell week num equals something?

E.G. I use a formula `=SUMIF(B2:B;WEEKNUM()=12;E2:E)` in cell `A1`.

What should I insert into `WEEKNUM()` brackets to compare each cell from range `B2:B` in `WEEKNUM(themselve)=12`. I want to sum from range `E2:E` (if `WEEKNUM(B2)=12` sum `E2` and next for `B3`).

Answer (score 0):

I would add a hidden column (let's say F) and place the formula `=weeknum(B2)` inside F2 (same for all in `F:F`). Then you can work with `=sumif(f2:f;12;e2:e)`.